# ImportError: cannot import name '_priv_parser', circular dependency

Tags: python, pip, importerror, circular-dependency

I struggled with this error on Pycharm, I'm using the BotCity framework and it wasn't barely starting running the script process when the following error was given:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "D:\path\padroniza_estilo_planilha.py", line 10, in <module>
>     from botcity.document_processing import *
File   "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botcity\document_processing\__init__.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>     from .parser import Entry, DocumentParser  # noqa: F401, F403
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botcity\document_processing\parser\__init__.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>     from .document import DocumentParser  # noqa: F401, F403
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botcity\document_processing\parser\document.py",
> line 4, in <module>`
>     from . import _priv_parser
> 
> ImportError: cannot import name '_priv_parser' from partially initialized module`'botcity.document_processing.parser'
> (most likely due to a circular import)
> (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botcity\document_processing\parser\__init__.py)
```

I've tried everything, mostly `pip install botcity-documents` and `pip install --upgrade botcity-documents` and it wasn't working well even tho apperently it should, since the "Successfully installed" message was given at the end of the installing.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is **disabling the antivirus** (I assumed the risk).
At the time of installation (pip install) the antivirus was indentifying the create file **_priv_parser.py** as a threat and moving it to quarentine, so when running the script the error was immediately thrown because the file wasn't finded/existed which at the end of it all resulted in **circular dependencies** between two other files (belonging to the same directory **document_processing**) of the process.

Comment: Hi, do you know why the file was flagged as a threat?

Comment: Hey!
The notification: "Threat blocked. We moved _priv_parser.py to quarentine, because it was infected with Python:Machete-A[Trj]."
It has something to do with a trojan threat I think, but I assumed the risk (my antivirus is a free version). I needed at the time.